# How to Reload UIViewController data of UIVIew

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, reload

How can I reload data of `UIVIewcontroller` from the `UIView`.Actually I have a `UIVIewController` which has a Custom class class of `UIView` .Now In `UIViewcontroller` i have a label and i need to print values of label which is been defined in the `UIView`.
but `viewdidload` of the `UIViewController` is been compiled firstly then compiler moves to `UIView`.then how can I print or Reload the `UIVIewController`

. `UILabel Text` I have defined in the `ViewDidLoad` of `UIViewController` and values taken from the `UIView` class

So How can I reload the `UIViewController`.

what I am doing is:

**UIVIewController**(thirdTab) class

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

 [self reloadInputViews1];

    }



-(void)reloadInputViews1{

appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
//  labelPrint.text=appDelegate.dayPrint;

[self.labelPrint setText:labelPrint.text];

}
```

**UIView** class

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.dayPrint=theDate;
    NSLog(@"appde%@",appDelegate.dayPrint);
    [appDelegate.thirdTab reloadInputViews1];
 }
```

But this does not work ...I am not able to print values in the label.how to do that..to get values from the UIViews

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call [`setNeedsDisplay`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/setNeedsDisplay) on your view to force it to be redrawn. But I am not sure that this is the best solution, in fact, instead of calling `setNeedsDisplay` on your view, you could call directly `reloadInputViews1` on your controller and it would be the same (actually, it would be much better).

Apart from this, I don´t think that your current design is very clean. I would suggest you to define a delegate protocol between your view and your controller to make that kind of relationship more explicit.

Comment: ya thanks ..but i don't think..defining delegate protocol would be work in my case bcz uiviewcontroller method is been called first....then uiview is been called... and i want to print label text from uiviewcontroller whose values is been defined in the UiView

Comment: as I said, use `setNeedsDisplay` to force your view to be redrawn. if this does not trigger an endless loop, than you are fine.

Comment: hey what i did in UIVIew [self.window setNeedsDisplay] and in UIViewcontroller `ViewWillAppear` i label to print ..it works fine

Comment: can you clear my doubt that `setNeedsDisplay` call only recall the `ViewWillAppear` method right??

Comment: `setNeedsDisplay` will trigger the `drawRect:` method of the view you send it to.