# Reload UITable call from asynchronous function

Tags: asynchronous, uiviewcontroller, swift

I am calling this chunk of code inside a callback function inside a http request. The the http request is a get that is used to update the app data. Thus, for some of the VCs I need to reload the view the instance the callback is done updating everything in Core Data.

Here is the chunk of code that I am currently using (called inside the callback function).

```
func reloadTopMost(){
    var topMost = topMostContoller() as UIViewController
    if topMost.isKindOfClass(SecondViewController){
        topMost.reloadInputViews()

        var svc = topMost as SecondViewController
        svc.studentTable.reloadData()
        svc.studentTable.setNeedsDisplay()
        svc.viewDidLoad()
        svc.reloadInputViews()
    }else if topMost.isKindOfClass(ThirdViewController){
        topMost.reloadInputViews()

        var tvc = topMost as ThirdViewController
        tvc.inClassTable.reloadData()
        tvc.inClassTable.setNeedsDisplay()
        tvc.viewDidLoad()
        tvc.reloadInputViews()
    }
}
```

As you can see I have tried reloadData(), setNeedsDisplay(), viewDidLoad, and reloadInputViews(). Ideas which I have gotten from answers to questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256931/how-to-reload-uiviewcontroller-data-of-uiview) one. I am certain that the if statements are passing for each the vc classes. So I am not sure why this is not reloading the VC/table. Is this because it is being called in an asynchronous function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this because it is being called in an asynchronous function?

That's probably the problem. There's a good chance that the callback is called in a background thread. UIKit is not thread safe and everything involving it must run on the main thread. Making sure `reloadTopMost()` runs on the main thread should solve the problem. You can use [`dispatch_async()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_async) to do that:

```
// In your callback:
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    self.reloadTopMost()
})
```

Please note that `dispatch_async()` returns immediately. If you need to wait until the reload is done, you can use [`dispatch_sync()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_sync).